# Convert falling 5 volt signal into latch circuit trigger

Tags: switches, low-power

I want to detect when a micro controller board has lost its wall PSU power, and use that knowledge to move it to a battery back up.

Specifically, I want to use a latch circuit like the one demonstrated [here](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/power-saving-latching-circuit/):

The schematic is:

[image]

This circuit uses a low to high pulse (or even low to high level works if you can eventually turn off the level to save power) to allow for a brief duration of the microcontroller board. During this brief start up time, the microcontroller board then sets a gpio pin high to ensure the battery stays on even when the trigger pulse is gone.

My desire is to use this type of circuit to prevent draining the battery when my micro controller has mains wall power.  But the easy way I have to know when the wall power is gone is when 5V pin goes away from the micro controller board (I'm using a seeed xiao esp32c3 board).

Is there a **component device** I can use that **acts like a normally closed switch only when it loses power from the 5V**?  Then when I have mains power I can command that **component device** to the open state and when I lose power it will go (normally) closed and act like the trigger for this circuit.

One **important note** here, the VCC in this diagram is from the battery, and the 5V level I am looking to use for the trigger (when it goes low) is from the wall PSU.  So when 5V goes away, I am planning to power the micro controller board through the 3.3V pin from this VCC from the battery. I was planning to use a CR2 lithium for example.

Comment: After talking to a friend more about this, it's probably best to just stick with the lipo setup I already have running for this that get's trickle charged and is available whenever needed to run the xiao board (which has the charging built in). Don't want to risk any charge (when plugged in to PSU) trying to go to a cr2 which was the only power source in that original tutorial I pointed to.

Comment: Instead of a heavy duty contactor might you be able to use a simple low power SPDT relay powered from the main power source? That would have a NC connection that would close if the main power to the relay coil was lost.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to use a latch circuit like the one demonstrated here

First let's look at the original circuit. It can be done with fewer components, and with zero static power consumption. The circuit below supports a latching ON and OFF switch, and also supports open-collector/open-drain logic inputs to turn it on and off.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzxGSU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you prefer active-high inputs, use two NOR gates instead. The external logic signals should be open-emitter/open-source type.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGod4C.png)</sup>

We can use this idea to drive four P-MOSFETS to switch between two power sources:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fM2gHX.png)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem you want to solve, a dual diode IC such as the TI LM66200 dual diode will do what you want.  It will switch to the higher input voltage and give you a status output so you know which input is being used.